# Button fixed position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to fix position of my button, cause when I click function `ShowContacts` loads and display contacts list on screen and my button go to footer page;

```
<button class="btn" 
    type="button" 
    id='button1' 
    style="visibility: hidden" 
    onclick="showContacts()">
        Show Contacts
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your question is tagged incorrect. This has nothing to do with jQuery.

To fix the button, add for example the following css:

```
.btn{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0:
}
```

which would fix it to the upper left corner of the page.

I strongly recommend that you learn about CSS first

**Further reading:**

[MDN CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**Edit:**

You could, however, accomplish this by using jquery:

```
$('.btn').css({
  'position':'fixed',
  // more rules
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS problem not JQuery, you can fix it by adding this :

```
#button1 {
 position: fixed; // or relative
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}
```

See more about positioning CSS elements : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: While your answer is correct, i would like to point to the following site, as you mentioned w3schools. I recommend to prefer other resources, e.g the MDN

http://w3fools.com/

Also, relative positioning will not fix the element